# How to register custom SiteMapNodeProvider Unity DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, mvcsitemapprovider

I have MvcSiteMapProvider MVC 5 version 4.6.17 with MvcSiteMapProvider MVC 5 unity modules installed, but I can't figure out how to register my implementation of ISiteMapNodeProvider. I assume I need to add my class to MvcSiteMapProviderContainerExtension but every attempt I have tried has failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**
I'm trying to create an implementation of ISiteMapNodeProvider that uses a db to populate that site map. I haven't added my db calls yet because I assume this will be trivial.

```
public class CustomSiteMapNodeProvider : ISiteMapNodeProvider
{
    private readonly string sourceName = "CustomSiteMapNodeProvider";


    public IEnumerable<ISiteMapNodeToParentRelation> GetSiteMapNodes(ISiteMapNodeHelper helper)
    {
        var result = new List<ISiteMapNodeToParentRelation>();
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

I've only made a slight change to the initial MvcSiteMapProviderContainerExtension class and that was adding a ReservedAttributeName.

```
 public class MvcSiteMapProviderContainerExtension
    : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        bool enableLocalization = true;
        string absoluteFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Mvc.sitemap");
        TimeSpan absoluteCacheExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        bool visibilityAffectsDescendants = true;
        bool useTitleIfDescriptionNotProvided = true;

        bool securityTrimmingEnabled = true;
        string[] includeAssembliesForScan = new string[] { "Ldi" };

        var currentAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
        var siteMapProviderAssembly = typeof(SiteMaps).Assembly;
        var allAssemblies = new Assembly[] { currentAssembly, siteMapProviderAssembly };
        var excludeTypes = new Type[] {};
        var multipleImplementationTypes = new Type[] {
            typeof(ISiteMapNodeUrlResolver),
            typeof(ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider),
            typeof(IDynamicNodeProvider)
        };

        // Matching type name (I[TypeName] = [TypeName]) or matching type name + suffix Adapter (I[TypeName] = [TypeName]Adapter)
        // and not decorated with the [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute].
        CommonConventions.RegisterDefaultConventions(
            (interfaceType, implementationType) => this.Container.RegisterType(interfaceType, implementationType, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()),
            new Assembly[] { siteMapProviderAssembly },
            allAssemblies,
            excludeTypes,
            string.Empty);

        // Multiple implementations of strategy based extension points (and not decorated with [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute]).
        CommonConventions.RegisterAllImplementationsOfInterface(
            (interfaceType, implementationType) => this.Container.RegisterType(interfaceType, implementationType, implementationType.Name, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()),
            multipleImplementationTypes,
            allAssemblies,
            excludeTypes,
            string.Empty);

        // TODO: Find a better way to inject an array constructor

        // Url Resolvers
        this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeUrlResolverStrategy, SiteMapNodeUrlResolverStrategy>(new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedArrayParameter<ISiteMapNodeUrlResolver>(this.Container.ResolveAll<ISiteMapNodeUrlResolver>().ToArray())
            ));

        // Visibility Providers
        this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy, SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>(new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedArrayParameter<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>(this.Container.ResolveAll<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider>().ToArray()),
            new InjectionParameter<string>("MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider")
            ));

        // Dynamic Node Providers
        this.Container.RegisterType<IDynamicNodeProviderStrategy, DynamicNodeProviderStrategy>(new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedArrayParameter<IDynamicNodeProvider>(this.Container.ResolveAll<IDynamicNodeProvider>().ToArray())
            ));


        // Pass in the global controllerBuilder reference
        this.Container.RegisterInstance<ControllerBuilder>(ControllerBuilder.Current);

        this.Container.RegisterType<IControllerTypeResolverFactory, ControllerTypeResolverFactory>(new InjectionConstructor(
            new List<string>(),
            new ResolvedParameter<IControllerBuilder>(),
            new ResolvedParameter<IBuildManager>()));

        // Configure Security

        // IMPORTANT: Must give arrays of object a name in Unity in order for it to resolve them.
        this.Container.RegisterType<IAclModule, AuthorizeAttributeAclModule>("authorizeAttribute");
        this.Container.RegisterType<IAclModule, XmlRolesAclModule>("xmlRoles");
        this.Container.RegisterType<IAclModule, CompositeAclModule>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedArrayParameter<IAclModule>(
            new ResolvedParameter<IAclModule>("authorizeAttribute"),
            new ResolvedParameter<IAclModule>("xmlRoles"))));

        this.Container.RegisterInstance<System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache>(System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default);
        this.Container.RegisterType(typeof(ICacheProvider<>), typeof(RuntimeCacheProvider<>));
        this.Container.RegisterType<ICacheDependency, RuntimeFileCacheDependency>(
            "cacheDependency", new InjectionConstructor(absoluteFileName));

        this.Container.RegisterType<ICacheDetails, CacheDetails>("cacheDetails",
            new InjectionConstructor(absoluteCacheExpiration, TimeSpan.MinValue, new ResolvedParameter<ICacheDependency>("cacheDependency")));

        // Configure the visitors
        this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeVisitor, UrlResolvingSiteMapNodeVisitor>();

        // Prepare for the sitemap node providers
        this.Container.RegisterType<IXmlSource, FileXmlSource>("file1XmlSource", new InjectionConstructor(absoluteFileName));
        this.Container.RegisterType<IReservedAttributeNameProvider, ReservedAttributeNameProvider>(new InjectionConstructor(new List<string>() { "type" }));

        // IMPORTANT: Must give arrays of object a name in Unity in order for it to resolve them.
        // Register the sitemap node providers
        this.Container.RegisterInstance<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("xmlSiteMapNodeProvider1", this.Container.Resolve<XmlSiteMapNodeProviderFactory>().Create(this.Container.Resolve<IXmlSource>("file1XmlSource")), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        this.Container.RegisterInstance<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("reflectionSiteMapNodeProvider1", this.Container.Resolve<ReflectionSiteMapNodeProviderFactory>().Create(includeAssembliesForScan), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeProvider, CompositeSiteMapNodeProvider>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedArrayParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>(
            new ResolvedParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("xmlSiteMapNodeProvider1"),
            new ResolvedParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("reflectionSiteMapNodeProvider1"))));

        // Configure the builders
        this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapBuilder, SiteMapBuilder>();

        // Configure the builder sets
        this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapBuilderSet, SiteMapBuilderSet>("builderSet1",
            new InjectionConstructor(
                "default",
                securityTrimmingEnabled,
                enableLocalization,
                visibilityAffectsDescendants,
                useTitleIfDescriptionNotProvided,
                new ResolvedParameter<ISiteMapBuilder>(),
                new ResolvedParameter<ICacheDetails>("cacheDetails")));

        this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapBuilderSetStrategy, SiteMapBuilderSetStrategy>(new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedArrayParameter<ISiteMapBuilderSet>(new ResolvedParameter<ISiteMapBuilderSet>("builderSet1"))));
    }
}
```

I think I just need to register my CustomSiteMapNodeProvider class by passing it to the CompositeSiteMapNodeProvider as a parameter, but everything I tried has failed.

Comment: Some information about what you are attempting to achieve and what your code looks like would be helpful. Do note that there is already a Unity example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387615/how-to-configure-multiple-sitemaps-using-using-mvcsitemapprovider-v4-with-unity

Comment: I looked at the Unity example, but couldn't figure out how to use a method other than xml given that solution. I've added my code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you just need to pass the CustomSiteMapNodeProvider instance to the CompositeSiteMapNodeProvider.

```
// IMPORTANT: Must give arrays of object a name in Unity in order for it to resolve them.
// Register the sitemap node providers
this.Container.RegisterInstance<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("xmlSiteMapNodeProvider1", this.Container.Resolve<XmlSiteMapNodeProviderFactory>().Create(this.Container.Resolve<IXmlSource>("file1XmlSource")), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
this.Container.RegisterInstance<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("reflectionSiteMapNodeProvider1", this.Container.Resolve<ReflectionSiteMapNodeProviderFactory>().Create(includeAssembliesForScan), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
// Register your custom SiteMapNodeProvider, and give it a name (required).
this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeProvider, CustomSiteMapNodeProvider>("customSiteMapNodeProvider");
this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeProvider, CompositeSiteMapNodeProvider>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedArrayParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>(
    new ResolvedParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("xmlSiteMapNodeProvider1"),
    new ResolvedParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("reflectionSiteMapNodeProvider1"),
    // Resolve your custom SiteMapNodeProvider instance.
    // Note the name must match the name above, and naming the registration is required in
    // Unity in order to resolve more than one implementation of an interface.
    new ResolvedParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("customSiteMapNodeProvider"))));
```

Or, the poor man's way of doing it if all else fails:

```
// IMPORTANT: Must give arrays of object a name in Unity in order for it to resolve them.
// Register the sitemap node providers
this.Container.RegisterInstance<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("xmlSiteMapNodeProvider1", this.Container.Resolve<XmlSiteMapNodeProviderFactory>().Create(this.Container.Resolve<IXmlSource>("file1XmlSource")), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
this.Container.RegisterInstance<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("reflectionSiteMapNodeProvider1", this.Container.Resolve<ReflectionSiteMapNodeProviderFactory>().Create(includeAssembliesForScan), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
this.Container.RegisterType<ISiteMapNodeProvider, CompositeSiteMapNodeProvider>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedArrayParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>(
    new ResolvedParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("xmlSiteMapNodeProvider1"),
    new ResolvedParameter<ISiteMapNodeProvider>("reflectionSiteMapNodeProvider1"),
    new CustomSiteMapNodeProvider())));
```

Basically, that is all Unity is doing in this scenario. But if your CustomSiteMapNodeProvider has dependencies, you should try to register it with the container so they can be injected automatically.

Comment: This answer works for me, but I had to remove the xmlsitemapnodeprovider. That's no problem, but I was just wondering if that is the way its supposed to work. And I will be injecting my dependencies via Unity. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that is the way it is supposed to work. At least 1 ISiteMapNodeProvider is required, but by no means do you need to use the pre-built ones to make it work. In fact, if you only intend to use 1, you can just replace the CompositeSiteMapNodeProvider with that 1 instance and do away with all of the naming strings.